# How to compute ESS (Effective Sample Size)?

Tags: python, iid, subsampling

I implemented the ESS calculation according to [this](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_20/reference-manual/effective-sample-size-section.html) manual like this:

```py
def neff(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    acf = sm.tsa.acf(arr, nlags = n, fft = True, unbiased = True)
    sums = 0
    for k in range(1, len(acf)):
        sums = sums + (n-k)*acf[k]/n

    return n/(1+2*sums)
```

then I perform a subsampling with $p= n_e/n$ as sample probability:

```py
def subsample(vector):
    p = neff(vector)/len(vector)
    np.random.seed(datetime.now().microsecond)
    arr = np.array([])
    for x in vector:
        if np.random.rand() < p: arr = np.concatenate((arr, [x]))
    return arr
```

and then I plot the correlogram of the subsampled vector:

```py
from statsmodels.graphics import tsaplots
tsaplots.plot_acf(df, lags = len(df)-1, fft = True, zero = False, unbiased = True)
```

expecting that the new data are incorrelated but it turns out that are still correlated. Is my function wrong? Or am I expecting something that should not happen?

Comment: Please tell us *how* you are subsampling and *how* you are estimating the correlation.  Could you present an example of the phenomenon you are asking about?

Comment: @whuber I edited the question

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear how you are subsampling and how you are estimating the correlation in your results, but your function systematically under-estimates the effective sample size by a factor of about 2.1 (but it's not exact, it varies, so maybe you have an off-by-one error in your implementation?) – I was looking for an implementation of ESS in python and found this question of yours before someone pointed me to [the `arviz` package](https://oriolabril.github.io/arviz/api/generated/arviz.ess.html), so I wrote a quick testing snipped using actually *iid* samples. (The `unbiased=True` option is not in [the `acf` function any more](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf.html), so I had to change that. This change may have introduced additional error.)

```
# Test effective sample size
import arviz
import functools
import numpy.random
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf as autocorr

def neff(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    acf = autocorr(arr, nlags=n, fft=True)
    sums = 0
    for k in range(1, len(acf)):
        sums = sums + (n-k)*acf[k]/n

    return n/(1+2*sums)


for ss in 20, 200, 2000, 20000:
    print()
    for function in [numpy.random.random, functools.partial(numpy.random.normal, 0, 1),
                 functools.partial(numpy.random.exponential, 1),
                 functools.partial(numpy.random.randint, 0, 2)]:
        for _ in range(6):
            iidsample = function(ss)
            print(ss / neff(iidsample), ss/arviz.ess(iidsample))
```

The output is consistently of the shape

```
2.2339282480243114 1.0305175002713263
2.5239571401740903 0.9713313105769105
2.155163047746372 0.9964616395724714
2.341650784172702 1.0357253893525886
2.1855457679897565 1.0135590911070333
2.5063442690680207 1.012734677889524
```

for all actual sample sizes, all random distributions, and all repetitions, so (a) `arviz.ess` gives a good estimate of the effective sample size (in that it properly estimates the sample size if the samples are actually independent) and (b) your function is systematically under-estimating effective sample size, in a manner that is not particularly correlated to the effective sample size according to `arviz.ess`.